# What large cardinals are needed to imply projective sets have the perfect set property?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

If there are infinitely many Woodins, then every projective set is determined, whence every projective set has the perfect set property (PSP). Since determinacy is such a stronger property than the PSP, it seems this should be overkill, and we should be able to prove that every projective set has the PSP from weaker assumptions. Indeed, in terms of consistency strength (rather than outright implication) we do know the gap: projective determinacy needs the Woodins while the PSP for projective sets only needs one inaccessible.

It's clear that no large cardinal consistent with $V = L$ suffices. And
Solovay's work mentioned in [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/78863/64676) and [this other related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/72252/64676) gives an epsilon more precise lower bound. But there's a pretty big gap from that to infinitely many Woodins.

Are more precise bounds known?

Comment: [Schindler and Wilson](https://doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2019.63) proved that the consistency strength of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with the perfect set property for universally Baire sets is equal to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with a large cardinal called *virtually Shelah cardinal,* whose consistency strength is below $0^\sharp$. It does not answer your question, but might be relevant.

Comment: Finitely many Woodins is not enough, because in $M_n$ (the minimal iterable proper class model with $n<\omega$ Woodin cardinals) it fails.

Comment: But "infinitely many Woodins" is certainly overkill, even for projective determinacy. By well known results, for that it suffices to have that for every $n<\omega$, $M_n^{\#}$ exists and is $\omega_1$-iterable.

Comment: @Farmer: So, more or less Con(ZFC+PD), right?

Comment: @FarmerS Thanks for the answer! If you want to write it as an answer instead of a comment I can accept it.